# Passing value borrowed from struct back to method on struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust, attempting to port some code from python. I'd like to ask a trait for its collection of objects, do some filtering on it, and then pass the objects back to a method on the trait, making it pick and return one of the objects. The borrow checker is giving me an error due to attempting to borrow multiple times; `cannot borrow *player as mutable when already borrowed as immutable`.

Example:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Player {
    fn items(&self) -> Vec<&Item>;
    fn items_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut Item>;
    fn should_choose_item<I: Borrow<Item>>(&self, possible_items: &Vec<I>) -> bool;
    fn choose_item<'a>(&'a self, _possible_items: Vec<&'a mut Item>) -> &'a mut Item;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    can_choose: bool,
    level: u8,
}

fn method<'a, P: Player>(player: &'a mut P) -> &'a mut Item {
    let mut possible_items = player.items();
    possible_items.retain(|dwarf| dwarf.can_choose);

    if player.should_choose_item(&possible_items) {
        let mut possible_items = player.items_mut();
        possible_items.retain(|i| i.can_choose);
        return player.choose_item(possible_items);
    }
    let mut possible_items = player.items_mut();
    possible_items.retain(|i| i.can_choose);
    possible_items.pop().unwrap()
}
```

Like I mentioned, I'm still learning rust, and so if there is a better architecture for doing this (getting some state from a trait object, processing it in some way, and then passing back to the trait), I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Are you sure you really want `Vec<&Item>` and `Vec<&mut Item>`? More likely you need `&Vec<Item>` ([or better, `&[Item]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)) and `&mut Vec<Item>`. Try to implement this trait and see if you succeed.

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check` (not your IDE).

Comment: Be aware that you can't have multiple `mut` references to the same item, or even a `mut` and a non-`mut` at the same time. That means, as long as you borrow `Vec<&mut>` from your struct, you **cannot** call `&self` methods on it, because those two references would alias.

Answer (score 0):

Not having the full idea of what you are trying to do here, I make some decision of what I think you wanted to do and what I would do in these case, just for your reference

```
trait IPlayer {
    fn items(&self) -> &Vec<Item>;
    fn items_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Item>;

    /* If you only use what inside the trait block you can have implementation of the function */
    fn get_level(&self) -> u8; // <-- here I added one more interface to get player's level

    fn should_choose(&self) -> bool {
        /*  this function will look through all item to see if there are item that are
            1 ) can_choose, and
            2 ) lower or equal to player's level
        */
        self
        .items()
        .iter()
        .fold(false, |acc, d| {
            (d.can_choose && d.level <= self.get_level()) || acc
        })
    }
    fn choose_item(&mut self) -> &mut Item {
        /*  this function will look through all item to pick the first item that
            1 ) can_choose, and
            2 ) lower or equal to player's level
            assuming such items exist therefore we unrwap the result

            *** notice this is not recommended, you should return a Option<>, but here I follow your code ***
        */
        let l = self.get_level();
        self.items_mut()
            .iter_mut()
            .filter(|d| d.can_choose && d.level <= l)
            .next()
            .unwrap()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    can_choose: bool,
    level: u8,
}

struct Dwarf {
    level: u8,
    player_items: Vec<Item>,
}
impl IPlayer for Dwarf {
    fn items(&self) -> &Vec<Item> { &self.player_items }
    fn items_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Item> { &mut self.player_items }
    fn get_level(&self) -> u8 {
        self.level
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut dwarf = Dwarf {
        level: 1,
        player_items: vec![
            Item {
                can_choose: true,
                level: 1,
            },
            Item {
                can_choose: true,
                level: 2,
            },
            Item {
                can_choose: false,
                level: 1,
            },
            Item {
                can_choose: false,
                level: 2,
            },
        ],
    };

    println!("{:?}", dwarf.should_choose()); // "true"
    println!("{:?}", dwarf.choose_item());   // "Item { can_choose: true, level: 1 }"
}
```

---

version that trait block don't have implementation

```
trait IPlayer {
    fn items(&self) -> &Vec<Item>;
    fn items_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Item>;
    fn should_choose(&self) -> bool;
    fn choose_item(&mut self) -> &mut Item;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    can_choose: bool,
    level: u8,
}

struct Dwarf {
    level: u8,
    player_items: Vec<Item>,
}
impl Dwarf{
    fn get_level(&self) -> u8 {
        self.level
    }
}
impl IPlayer for Dwarf {
    fn items(&self) -> &Vec<Item> { &self.player_items }
    fn items_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Item> { &mut self.player_items }
    fn should_choose(&self) -> bool {
        /*  this function will look through all item to see if there are item that are
            1 ) can_choose, and
            2 ) lower or equal to player's level
        */
        self
        .items()
        .iter()
        .fold(false, |acc, d| {
            (d.can_choose && d.level <= self.get_level()) || acc
        })
    }
    fn choose_item(&mut self) -> &mut Item {
        /*  this function will look through all item to pick the first item that
            1 ) can_choose, and
            2 ) lower or equal to player's level
            assuming such items exist therefore we unrwap the result

            *** notice this is not recommended, you should return a Option<>, but here I follow your code ***
        */
        let l = self.get_level();
        self.items_mut()
            .iter_mut()
            .filter(|d| d.can_choose && d.level <= l)
            .next()
            .unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut dwarf = Dwarf {
        level: 1,
        player_items: vec![
            Item { can_choose: true,  level: 1, },
            Item { can_choose: true,  level: 2, },
            Item { can_choose: false, level: 1, },
            Item { can_choose: false, level: 2, },
        ],
    };

    println!("{:?}", dwarf.should_choose()); // "true"
    println!("{:?}", dwarf.choose_item());   // "Item { can_choose: true, level: 1 }"
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this solves the issue; I don't want any implementation of `Player` to override the logic that determines if a given item is valid or not; that should live in the caller. with your example, it's possible for `Dwarf` to override `should_choose`

Comment: yes, of course, you can put the implementation of `Player` inside the `Dwarf`, I am just pointing out that in your `fn method` all the function called is inside of `trait Player`, therefore you can have the implementation inside of `Player`. Also, I need concrete implementation to actually test the code, that's why I added my own implementation. I've added a version where the `trait` block doesn't have any implementation.